# ReadOnly Property Request As System.Web.HttpRequest is not accessible in this context because it is Friend

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httprequest

I need to read the values of the context of an ashx handler.

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim Resp As System.Web.HttpResponse = context.Response
        Dim dd = Resp.Request... ' HERE COMES THE ERROR
    End Sub
```

The problem is that I get the following error when I try to read the values located at `dd.Request.Response.Request.Form`

> ReadOnly Property Request As System.Web.HttpRequest is not accessible in this context because it is Friend

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you do:

```
Dim dd = context.Request 'Access the http request from the context instead of the response
```

Is there a reason why you are using the response to get the request?

HTH.

Comment: No, there is no such reason! I am just a newbie! Thank you very much!